# Under what conditions on $A \subseteq X^2$ is the function $F_A(\gamma) := \gamma(A)$ l.s.c on the space of finite Borel measures $\mathscr M(X^2)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, optimal-transport

Let $X$ be a topological space (assumed to be [Polish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_space), if that helps) and let $\mathscr M(X^2)$ be the space of finite Borel measures on the product space $X^2$. Let $A$ be a nonempty subset of $X^2$.

> **Question.** Under what conditions (on the subset $A$)  is the function $F_A:\mathscr M(X^2) \to \mathbb R$ defined by $F_A(\gamma) := \gamma(A)$ lower-semicontinuous ?

Comment: If $X$ is Polish, then $X^2$ is also Polish, and $F_A$ will at least be l.s.c. for $A$ closed.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou: It seems to me that we need "open" instead of "closed", by considering point masses.

Comment: I might be mixing up which one is upper and which is lower semi-continuity. Isn't the requirement that $\{F_A<t\}$ is open for all $t$? If we need $\{F_A>t\}$ to be open, then I agree that we need $A$ open.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou: Yeah, it's the second one.  I have to refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-continuity every single time.

Comment: Is $\mathscr{P}(X^2)$ the set of **all** Borel measures, or only the set of Borel probability measures (as the notation would suggest)?  If the former, what's the topology?  If the latter, I assume the weak topology.

Comment: It's probably the weak topology anyway, right?

Comment: @WoolierThanThou: Well, I don't know how to define a weak topology on the space of **all** Borel measures (including the infinite ones).  If it were the **finite** Borel measures then sure.

Comment: Sorry, I meant finite Borel measures. Fixed.

Comment: Oh sure... I still don't know if there is a much bigger class than open $A$ for which this is true.

Comment: I believe this is if and only if $A$ is open.  The converse direction is actually easier, a short exercise.  I can try to add details later if needed.

Comment: Thanks to both for the valuable input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We might as well work on $X$ instead of $X^2$, since the product plays no role here.  I will assume only that $X$ is a metric space, and that $\mathscr{M}(X)$ carries the weak topology.

The answer is that $F_A$ is lsc if and only if $A$ is open.

The key fact is that in a metric space, for an open set $A$, the indicator function $1_A$ can be written as an increasing pointwise limit of a uniformly bounded sequence of  continuous functions $f_n$.  Indeed, we can take $f_n(x) = \min(1, n \cdot d(x, A^c))$.  Therefore if we let $F_n(\gamma) = \int f_n\,d\gamma$, the function $F_n$ is continuous on $\mathscr{M}(X)$, and the monotone convergence theorem shows that $F_n(\gamma) \uparrow F_A(\gamma)$ for each $\gamma$.  Thus $F_A$ is lsc.

Conversely, if $A$ is a set with $F_A$ lsc, let $x_n \in A^c$ with $x_n \to x$.  Letting $\delta_{x_n}$ be the corresponding Dirac measures, we have $\delta_{x_n} \to \delta_x$ in the weak topology.  Now $F_A(\delta_{x_n}) = 0$ for each $n$, so by lower semicontinuity $F_A(\delta_x) \le 0$, which is to say $x \notin A$.  So we have shown $A^c$ is closed.

Comment: Great, thanks. Here is my argument for one direction. Suppose $A$ is open. For any $t \in \mathbb R$, we show that $S_t := \{\gamma \mid F_A(\gamma) \le t\}$ is closed in $\mathscr M(X^2)$. Indeed, let $\gamma$ be a limit point of $S_t$. Then there is a sequence $(\gamma_n)_n \subset S_t$ such that $\gamma_n \to \gamma$ (weak). Thus, $F_A(\gamma) := \gamma(A) \le \lim\inf_n\gamma_n(A) \le t$, i.e $\gamma \in S_t$.

Comment: @dohmatob: Sure, that works too.